# some question about append built-in function

Tags: arrays, go, append

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    
)

func main() {
    result := subsets([]int{9,3,0,1,2})
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    var fun func([]int, int)
    fun = func (preSets []int, start int) {
        // fmt.Println(start, preSets, result)
        result = append(result, preSets)
        // fmt.Println(result)
        for idx := start; idx < len(nums); idx++ {
            tmp := nums[idx]
            newSet := append(preSets, tmp)
            fun(newSet, idx+1)
            newSet = newSet[:len(newSet) - 1]
        }
    }

    fun([]int{}, 0)
    return result
}
```

i want to find the subsets of a slice, and think the code above should work. but it give me the following output

```
[[] [9] [9 3] [9 3 0] [9 3 0 2] [9 3 0 1 2] [9 3 0 2] [9 3 1] [9 3 1 2] [9 3 2] [9 0] [9 0 1] [9 0 1 2] [9 0 2] [9 1] [9 1 2] [9 2] [3] [3 0] [3 0 1] [3 0 1 2] [3 0 2] [3 1] [3 1 2] [3 2] [0] [0 1] [0 1 2] [0 2] [1] [1 2] [2]]
```

the fifth slice should be [9 3 0 1], but it is [9 3 0 2],and i print the result each step, i found out that the fifth slice turned from [9301] to [9302] when the seventh slice [9302] is appended,i think it should be related to the array storage under the slice, but why

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices, https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#append, https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15, etc. The mechanics of append are well documented.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? The code shown is very convoluted, it's hard to tell exactly what behavior of append you're asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i think [the problem is] related to the array storage under the slice

Yes, it is.

> but why

The `append` function:

- sometimes re-uses the original backing array, but
- sometimes creates a new backing array and copies the original values to the new array.

There are no promises made about *when* it does one of these two.

When it re-uses the original array, you encounter the behavior you dislike.  When it makes a new array, you encounter the behavior you desire.  Since you want the copy behavior, you can simply write your own "always copy" code and get the behavior you want.  However, a more-minimal change is to replace:

```
result = append(result, preSets)
```

with:

```
result = append(result, unshare(preSets))
```

with the function `unshared` defined as:

```
func unshare(a []int) []int {
    tmp := make([]int, len(a))
    copy(tmp, a)
    return tmp
}
```

If you are trying to explain to yourself *exactly* why you got the *exact* result that you got, it's a little tricky because you're not promised anything about when `append` makes a new backing array and when it re-uses the existing backing array—but it *is* explainable, if you make the following two assumptions:

1. `append` never makes a copy of the backing array if it does not have to; and
2. when `append` does make a copy, it sometimes over-allocates the new backing array by some factor.

That is, `append` behaves more or less like this, except of course this one is specific to `[]int`:

```golang
func xappend(orig []int, add []int) []int {
    has := len(orig)
    needed := has + len(add)
    // If we can fit the added elements in, do that now.
    if cap(orig) >= needed {
        fmt.Println("copy in place")
        orig = orig[:needed]
        copy(orig[has:needed], add)
        return orig
    }
    newSize := undocumentedFunction(has, cap(orig), needed)
    fmt.Println("make new, size", newSize)
    new := make([]int, needed, newSize)
    copy(new, orig)
    copy(new[has:needed], add)
    return new
}

func undocumentedFunction(oldCap, oldLen, newCap int) int {
    twiceAsMuch := oldCap + oldCap
    if newCap > twiceAsMuch {
        return newCap
    }
    // 2x old capacity is enough, but
    // we'll tweak this in various ways.
    // The exact tweaks might change at any time.
    if oldLen < 1024 {
        return twiceAsMuch
    }
    panic("didn't copy this part")
}
```

This "undocumented function" is part of the runtime system, and it collaborates with the compiler.  You can see its actual code [here](https://golang.org/src/runtime/slice.go#L115) (note: this link may break or go to the wrong line at some point).

(Sample runnable code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/cjXEbz4EUst) on the Go Playground.)